# Storage event does not fire for localStorage in Office

Tags: javascript, local-storage, ms-office, internet-explorer-11, office-js

I’m trying to use the [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onstorage) in an Office.js app **on Office Desktop** but it works only for `sessionStorage`, not `localStorage`.

While the storage event works perfectly fine for `localStorage`…

- in IE11 in general ([try this demo](https://bestvpn.org/html5demos/storage-events/)),
- on Office **Online** in Chrome,
- on Office **Online** in IE11,

…it seems to work only for `sessionStorage` when running in the **Office Desktop** applications (where IE11 is utilized).

This is the code I’m using for testing:

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');

window.addEventListener('storage', ev => {
  output.innerHTML += `${ev.key} changed to ${ev.newValue}<br>`;
});

document.getElementById('writels').addEventListener('click', () => { 
  localStorage.setItem('lstest', (+new Date()).toString());
});

document.getElementById('writess').addEventListener('click', () => {
  sessionStorage.setItem('sstest', (+new Date()).toString());
});
```

And this is the HTML construct it’s working with:

```html
<button id="writels">Write to localStorage</button>
<button id="writess">Write to sessionStorage</button>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Setting the values works perfectly fine for both `sessionStorage` **and** `localStorage`, but the event gets **only** fired on `sessionStorage` changes.

Comment: localStorage events don't fire in the same browser window, have you another window open to view the events.?

Comment: Can you please explain with more details like how IE is utilized in your Office JS app? Are you using any Web browser Control in your app?

Comment: @Keith I already tried this by creating a simple Office.js content add-in with Firebug Lite because, other than taskpane add-ins, there can be multiple instances of a content add-in on the same Excel sheet. But still, the `window.onstorage` function doesn’t get executed in either add-in when changing a `localStorage` value, only in the same add-in when changing a `sessionStorage` value.
@Deepak-MSFT I’m using the stock IE11 runtime implementation that’s used for Office.js-based add-ins in Office Desktop.